# I am Building a Youtube subscribe download gate.. and I want a button to appear after clicking the subscribe button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hey Guys I want to build a YouTube Subscribe Gate...
Where the files can be downloaded only if the subscribe button is clicked.
Here have a YouTube Subscribe Button and on clicking subscribe, I want a button to appear with the download link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make two buttons

1. To subscribe (say, `id='subscribe'`)
2. To download (say, `id='download'`)

And hide the download button using CSS

```
#download { visibility: hidden; }
```

Then create the first button as

```
<button id="subscribe" href="xyz" onclick="download();">Subscribe</button>
```

And in the  tag for Javascript, write a function:

```
function download() {
    document.getElementById("subscribe").visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("download").visibility = "visible";
}
```

This will hide the 'subscribe' and show the download button, once 'subscribe' has been clicked.

Comment: Yes, But YouTube Provides its own Subscribe Button, How can i know its ID?

Answer (score 0):

YouTube's subscribe button won't be helpful, as it isn't really a subscribe button.  It takes people off your page and brings them to your channel.  It can still be useful though.  Just go here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button

Put in your channel ID and grab the code.